# No results in Australia using Bing Maps SOAP

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, bing-maps

I'm creating an app for WP8 and i've been using the Bing Maps tutorial. However I don't get any results in Australia. Do I need to use a completely different API? `geolocale` contains a string such as `"20.002, -150.2222"` even if I change it to just `"California"` it gets results. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried to find answers in a lot of places but can't seem to find anything that's relevant.

```
         try
        {
            searchService.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<SearchService.SearchCompletedEventArgs>(MySearchCompleted);

            SearchService.SearchRequest mySearchRequest = new SearchService.SearchRequest();
            mySearchRequest.Credentials = new SearchService.Credentials();
            mySearchRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = "key";

            SearchService.StructuredSearchQuery ssQuery = new SearchService.StructuredSearchQuery();
            ssQuery.Keyword = "coffee";
            ssQuery.Location = geolocale;
            mySearchRequest.StructuredQuery = ssQuery;

            searchService.SearchAsync(mySearchRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Still not really sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinate 20.002, -150.2222 is in the middle of the Pacific ocean. Also, the Bing Maps SOAP services are an old legacy API. The Bing Spatial Data Services should be used. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701734.aspx
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/dynamically-updating-data-in-bing-maps-v7/

Comment: Thanks for the links mate. Because of the roadblocks I kept facing, i've started the project again on a fresh slate. It's been so confusing trying to figure out which map service to use.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example to use this in my WP8 app? I don't need an actual map to be visible, I just want to list nearby coffee and the store name and distance from your location.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Bing Spatial Data Services in WP8 first copy the Response, ResultSet, and Result classes from this project: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Augmented-Reality-with-bcb17045/sourcecode?fileId=85735&pathId=1819751232

You can then use the following code to generate your search query.

```
string baseURL; 

//Switch between the NAVTEQ POI data sets for NA and EU based on where the user is. 
if (Longitude < -30) 
{ 
    //Use the NAVTEQ NA data source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478192.aspx 
    baseURL = "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    //Use the NAVTEQ EU data source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478193.aspx 
    baseURL = "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/c2ae584bbccc4916a0acf75d1e6947b4/NavteqEU/NavteqPOIs"; 
} 

//Search radius should be converted from meters to KM.
string poiRequest = string.Format("{0}?spatialFilter=nearby({1:N5},{2:N5},{3:N2})&$format=json&$top={4}&key={5}", 
    baseURL, Latitude, Longitude, SearchRadius / 1000, MaxResultsPerQuery, BingMapsKey);
```

You will need a method to pass this query to and serialize the results. Use the following:

```
private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback) 
{ 
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
    client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, a) => 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            using (var stream = a.Result) 
            { 
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response)); 

                if (callback != null) 
                { 
                    callback(ser.ReadObject(stream) as Response); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            if (callback != null) 
            { 
                callback(null); 
            } 
        } 
    }; 
    client.OpenReadAsync(uri); 
}
```

Finally you will need to call the GetResponse method to make your query like this:

```
GetResponse(new Uri(poiRequest), (response) => 
{ 
    if (response != null && 
        response.ResultSet != null && 
        response.ResultSet.Results != null && 
        response.ResultSet.Results.Length > 0) 
    { 
        //Do something with the results
    }
});
```

Comment: Champion. I'll check this out and see if I can get it working correctly. Thanks for taking the time to respond.